# cx_oracle: can callfunc return list?

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

I'm trying to write a PL/SQL function that returns an array of integers and then be able to call it with cx_Oracles callfunc. I think I got the PL/SQL function right, but I don't know how to call it with cx_Oracle.

`create or replace type test_type is table of NUMBER(10);`

```
create or replace function test_function (n in INTEGER)
RETURN test_type
AS
  tmp_tab test_type := test_type();
BEGIN
  tmp_tab.EXTEND(n);
  FOR i IN 1 .. n LOOP
    tmp_tab(i) := i;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN tmp_tab;
END;
```

It works with sqlplus:

```
SQL> select test_function(20) from dual;

TEST_FUNCTION(20)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST_TYPE(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```

How can I get the result of such function using cx_Oracle? Is that possible?

I've found this http://osdir.com/ml/python.db.cx-oracle/2005-06/msg00014.html but I don't realy know how to use it. When I change my type definition to:

```
create or replace type test_type is table of NUMBER(10) index by binary_integer;
```

I get:
    Warning: Type created with compilation errors.

```
SQL> sho err
Errors for TYPE TEST_TYPE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0  PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/19     PLS-00355: use of pl/sql table not allowed in this context
```

Answer (score 1):

Something in the lines of,

```
import cx_Oracle

db_sid = 'db_sid'
db_usr = 'schema'
db_pwd = 'passwd'

conn_data = str('%s/%s@%s') % (db_usr, db_pwd, db_sid)

try:
    db = ora.connect(conn_data)
    except ora.DatabaseError, e:
    error, = e
    ORAmessage = error.message.rstrip("\n")
    print "DatabaseError: %s" % ORAmessage
else:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    try:
        out_parameter = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
        # calling function to retrieve results until 20
        execute_func  = cursor.callfunc('test_function', out_parameter, [20])
        print str(return_value.getvalue())
    except ora.DatabaseError, exc:
        error, = exc
        ORAmessage = error.message.rstrip("\n")
        print "DatabaseError: %s" % ORAmessage
    cursor.close()

db.close()
```

Reading this part of the
[manual](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/module.html#types) will also be useful.

Comment: The return_value in this line: `execute_func  = cursor.callfunc('test_function', return_value, [20])` is not defined. What should it be?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I get 
>>> execute_func = cursor.callfunc('test_function', out_parameter, [20])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: It's because you're returning as *TEST_TYPE*(1, 2, 3, 4,... ) and not accessing columns in a database that are numbers. Try switching cx_Oracle.NUMBER to cx_Oracle.OBJECT.

Comment: >>> out_parameter = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.OBJECT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: expecting type name for object variables

Comment: I'm sorry to not be of further help, my PL/SQL experience is quite limited, I usually access both procedures and functions with .cursor.callfunc with no issues.